# Web Scraping Pop-Up

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to Web Scraping and I am trying to automate retrieving parcel information from a town website. I have over 300 parcels I need the book and page number for.

This is the website:
https://newmilfordct.mapgeo.io/datasets/properties?abuttersDistance=100&latlng=41.587864%2C-73.425014

When you go there you can click on search and then I would put in the identifier (example would be 68/20). I have a list of all these. From there the profile comes up and I can get the book and page number.

This is what I have so far

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = "https://newmilfordct.mapgeo.io/datasets/properties?abuttersDistance=100&latlng=41.587864%2C-  73.425014"
page = urlopen(url)
html = page.read().decode("utf-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

I connect to the site but I cannot figure out how to interact with it.
If someone could please assist me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated and hours of work saved by hand.

Comment: what's the desired output ?

Comment: This seems like a selenium thing..as you need to click/interact with the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the data for the given identifier by sending a `POST` request to the `API` url.

Here's how to do it:

```
import requests

search_url = "https://newmilfordct.mapgeo.io/api/datasets/properties/search?format=json"

identifier = "68/20"

payload = {
    "page": 1,
    "quickSearch": identifier
}

search_results = requests.post(search_url, payload).json()
# print(search_results)

for item in search_results:
    name = item['displayName']
    owner = item['ownerName']
    geometry = item['geometry']
    book = item['lastSaleBook']
    page = item['lastSalePage']
    print(f"Name: {name} | Owner: {owner}")
    print(f"Book/Page: {book}/{page}")
    print(geometry)
    print("-" * 80)
```

Output:

```
Name: 17 BUCKINGHAM LN | Owner: ROTELLI LOUIS
Book/Page: 0970/230
{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-73.4909038060549,41.6425898231357],[-73.4909821900848,41.6425591025291],[-73.4907493168393,41.6419510845828],[-73.4911769908149,41.6420353877],[-73.4915429751214,41.6418889484739],[-73.4915515509607,41.6418998161938],[-73.4919447199921,41.6423992451082],[-73.4920405021311,41.6425204818934],[-73.4919930203487,41.6425307775562],[-73.4919273071398,41.6425305146988],[-73.4917614178846,41.642552550643],[-73.491595684262,41.642581803258],[-73.4910018358319,41.6426901884681],[-73.4910019510053,41.6427258656192],[-73.4909038060549,41.6425898231357]]]}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name: 15 BUCKINGHAM LN | Owner: NEELANDS DOUGLAS S + SALOME S
Book/Page: 0330/394
{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-73.4904204439222,41.6413365201908],[-73.4908759926496,41.6411167792846],[-73.4909181970441,41.6410961714263],[-73.4915429751214,41.6418889484739],[-73.4911769908149,41.6420353877],[-73.4907493168393,41.6419510845828],[-73.4909821900848,41.6425591025291],[-73.4909038060549,41.6425898231357],[-73.4904204439222,41.6413365201908]]]}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

There's much more in the JSON. Just uncomment this line `# print(search_results)` to get the entire response.

EDIT: A short note on the `API`.

You can take a sneak-peek at what happens when you drop the identifier into the search field in the Developer Tool in your web browser. Then go to the `Network` tab and select the `XHR` filter.

Select the first item and choose `Headers`. There you will find the `Request URL` and the `Request payload`.

Comment: That's worked great thank you so much!
If you don't mind me asking where did you find the api. I looked all over the source code on the website and didn't see anything referencing that link.

Comment: Thank you for the information. This is my first time ever doing this and I didnt understand its capabilities till now.